# How to inject some string and evaluate it in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework

in a SPA, using options API, how (where) to define a function that will be called from an html href?

In the following codepen for demo, everything works fine.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/ijose/pen/NWMeKbM)

However, on my Single Page:

```
    <template>
        <div v-html="my_div" />
    </template>
    
    <script>
    /* function MyFunction() {
      alert();
    }; */
    
    const MyFunction = () => {
      alert();
    };

   /* Just for explanation, because the data comes from the database
   export default {
    data() {
      return {
        my_div:'<a href="javascript:MyFunction(10)">link call function</a> ',
      }
    }
  */
}
    </script>
```

call the function return the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined

Apparently, the function is defined after the call

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you're using Options API, define it in `methods` I'd say. Otherwise, do not forget `export default {`. Also, where are you supposed to call `MyFunction` from?

Comment: I already tried this solution, but it didn't work. In CODEPEN for demonstration, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Not sure about codepen but here you go: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpFkEtuwzAMRK8icJMEaKx94BZtN71Al9zYCl071Q8S1Q+C3L20XDuAIGio4cOQV3iJsfkqBCdos0lT5Cf0Q/GGp+CV6ax9Df3+oK7oleosJd7v+tDvDuhv6OknhsTqTENXLC8mRzyGcz4tSlXG+0hv5XfFrNVKXgrCqpecVm85RDC5aDsmUUq1fWGWWM/GTubzEeHORqgOpXJxTiw80hJXjZSoNuulW3yt3rDwAJObhzi6LjaXHLxsoqbE/4+MsM2CIKuaNcLIHPNJ6zyYeX+X3IT0oeXVpOJ5ctRQdsc+he9MScAI64hw+wP7Wn9u

Comment: Thanks kissu. From the click the event of a button it works perfect. But the function is called from a href rendered in a div, like in my CODEPEN

Comment: The string that you're trying to casually is a very bad idea because it's not secure, it doesn't lead to any kind of good programming design, can be done far better with render functions etc. I also don't see the point of doing so, I recommend that you actually write down what you actually want here otherwise it will be an XY problem. Even from an HTML standing point, it doesn't like good or anything, just some kind of fishy JS injection to me. Who runs code on an href?

Comment: Yes, I agree with with a lot of what you say, but it's one of the options I have to consider. Another solution I'm considering is a href for a route, more expensive in my real case. The MyFunction method would just change a data property from false to true. my_div its just a link for small additional information related with link.

Comment: I saw your other post too, as strange as this one. Why don't you use regular things here? What's the point of such script evaluation? I recommend following good principles and code standards.

Comment: Well sometimes we have a legacy system that you can't make big changes to. Thanks.

Comment: Here, a refacto is needed for sure. Don't spend hours trying to hack Vue and do something out of it. It's not worth it and it will not work any better. You can use jQuery for such websites.

Comment: I will have to consider that too. If you don't mind, I'll delete this question. Thank you for helping me to reflect on the matter.

Comment: No need to delete it, can still serve as a reference for things to not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do here but don't evaluate some random string coming from nowhere into a weird format. It will not work, will be clunky, non-debuggable.

If your codebase is legacy and has a lot of debt, refacto it or use jQuery or whatever to hack it even further.